# Printing uint64_t* value in C

Tags: c, uint64

I am using the following code:

```
    size_t offset = (rand() << 12) % chunk_size;
    uint64_t *addr = (uint64_t*) (chunk+offset);
    fprintf(stdout,"addr: %" PRIx64 " ", addr);
```

I included `<inttypes.h>` library but i got the folowwing error:

```
error: format ‘%lx’ expects argument of type ‘long unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘uint64_t *’ {aka ‘long unsigned int *’} [-Werror=format=]
fprintf(stdout,"addr: %" PRIx64 " ", addr);  
                                       uint64_t * {aka long unsigned int *}

In file included from filename.c:5:
/usr/include/inttypes.h:121:34: note: format string is defined here
  121 | # define PRIx64  __PRI64_PREFIX "x"
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [Makefile:8: filename.o] Error 1
```

why?

thank you.

Comment: You are not trying to print `uint64_t` as you claim. Use `%p` for pointers or dereference the pointer if you really are trying to print the `uint64_t` value.

Comment: `uint64_t addr = (uint64_t) ()...` though of course you could just print `size_t` with `%zu`

Comment: @kaylum what does it means ?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala addr is a uint64_t so why should i print a %zu value ?

Comment: No, `addr` is not `uint64_t`. It is `uint64_t *`. As far as C is concerned they are different types.

Comment: @kaylum ok i got it, so how can i print  a uint64_t* ? what the format is ?

Comment: @kaylum of course, and that is what i need

Comment: I told you in my first comment. `%p` for pointers.

Comment: @Nick you don't want to print `uint64_t *` because you do not have it. You have a number, not a pointer.

Comment: `fprintf(stdout,"addr: %p", (void*)addr);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the type you want to print is an `uint64_t *` and not a `uint64_t`,
so if you want to print the pointer(`addr`) just use `%p` in the `printf`, else you need to dereference the pointer using the `*`.

Comment: Technically, `%p` requires a parameter of type `void *`, so `addr` should be changed to `(void *)addr` in the `fprintf` function call. In practice, other pointer types also work, but that is not guaranteed by the C standard.